# Usage of 'insofar as' and 'to the extent that'

Tags: phrase-usage

I do not really know how to use the two phrases in a grammatically correct way.

Also, are there any difference in meaning between the two?

Thank you.

Comment: They're both 'business-speak' speech-fillers. You could remove them & not lose a thing ;)

Answer (score 1):

To the extent that someone is learning English, they will probably find ell.stackexchange.com useful. But insofar as they are already fairly expert in the language, they would be better looking at english.stackexchange.com

They mean the same thing.